# region locales do not work on iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I need to add region locale for Switzerland to my app which already has the normal German localization.

So I just added it and now have a Localizable.String for Switzerland in my project. On the phone I set language to German and region to Switzerland.

But when I select German as language and Switzerland for region the code still shows the German text not picking up the translation from the swiss file.

All the other normal country locales work fine.

Is this a bug in iOS ?

Many thinks

Comment: are you using google place api for localization?

Comment: I am on iOS, not using any google api...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no swiss language in the General-International-Language menu meaning you can't select it for localization. And the region is responsible for the formatting (e.g. date, time and currency formats).

Comment: Yes, but in xCode there is a Swiss localization. I guess you are right - I was hoping that the region wil also influence the language files, not only the formatting.

Comment: That must be because the same SDK is used for iOs and OS X development and OS X supports more languages.